# Is it safe to put the milk left after feeding in the fridge for the next feed?

Tags: safety, breastfeeding, bottle-feeding, formula

We use bottle to feed the infant with formula/breast milk.

Considering:  https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/8404/2221

> Discard any infant formula remaining after a feeding. The mixture of infant formula with saliva provides an ideal breeding ground for disease-causing micro-organisms.

Is it safe to put the formula/breast milk left (in the bottle) after feeding ***in the fridge*** for the next feed (from the same bottle)?

Comment: If you mix up a full bottle (eg 8 oz) and then pour out 4 oz into another container, feed the first 4 to the child and don't need the second 4, you can refrigerate that. But any product that's been in the bottle and the bottle has been in a mouth, don't refrigerate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal advice for formula is that you should not re-use a bottle that has been partially used, in line with the advice given above.

The advice for breastmilk is different (breastmilk naturally has [antimicrobial properties](http://kellymom.com/bf/can-i-breastfeed/illness-surgery/healing-breastmilk/)) so it is [generally considered OK](http://kidshealth.org/parent/growth/feeding/breastfeed_storing.html) to re-use a bottle of breastmilk. It can be stored at room temperature for up to an hour and in the fridge until the next feed.

That said, once you know how much your baby usually takes, and to avoid wastage, you may find it's easier to store breast milk in small portions so you can make up only the amount needed, or make up only the amount of formula required.